# You have $12$ female and $8$ male employees. How many ways can you choose a committee of $5$ people with at least one male and one female?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I understand the solution given in my book, but I fail to understand why my solution is wrong.
My thinking is that there are $5$ positions in the committee, and since there must be at least one male and one female, call one slot the male slot and the other the female slot.
There are $12$ females to choose from for the female slot, and $8$ males to choose from for the male slot. The remaining are $18$ people from which we need to choose $3$ to be on the committee.
So why is the answer not equal to $12\cdot8\binom{18}{3}$?

Comment: How did you get $128$? There are $96$ pairs of female and male employees.

Comment: @JohnDouma The $128$ you saw was intended to be $12\cdot 8$ but was typed as `12*8*`.  I reformatted it just now.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose Alex goes into the male slot.  And some girl fills the female slot.  Then you enumerate all solutions starting there.  {Alex, Bob, Charlie, Dan, Girl} will be among the ones counted.

Next Bob goes into the male slot, and the same female.  You enumerate all solutions starting there.  {Bob, Alex, Charlie, Dan, Girl} will be among the ones counted.

So you counted that solution twice.  And you will again when Charlie is selected, and then again again when Dan is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You overcount a lot. Change a man from the male slot with a man from the rest of the committee (if there is one). It’s the same committee, but you count both as if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a smaller example with $2$ females and $2$ males where you must select a committee of $3$ with at least $1$ of each.  Your approach would yield $2\cdot2\binom{4-2}{3-2}=4\binom{2}{1}=8$ when the correct count is instead $4$.