# Why is this method incorrect? (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 3 sections in a question paper and each section contains 5 questions. A candidate has to answer a total of 5 questions, choosing at least one question from each section. Then the number of ways, in which the candidate can choose the questions, is:
(A) 2250
(B) 2255
(C) 1500
(D) 3000

What I did: 5×5×5×12C2

5's for choosing one question from each section and selecting 2 more from remaining 12 to complete the required amount

correct method: 3(5C1×5C1×5C3)+3(5C2×5C2×5C1)

I am unable to understand why is my method incorrect

Comment: You have overcounted because you have designated three questions as special representatives for each section. For example if you chose 3 questions from the first section, one from the second section, and one from the third section, your approach counts this particular outcome 3 times instead of 1 time.

Comment: Read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862556/you-have-12-female-and-8-male-employees-how-many-ways-can-you-choose-a-comm/4862564#4862564) for a discussion of a very similar problem. They overcounted the same way as you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options are being counted more than once.

First, you choose 1 question from each section (indeed, there are $5\times 5\times 5$ ways of doing this). Then, you select two more questions.

Your way, you simply select any 2 questions without accounting for the fact that you may have already counted this options. To explain, let us number the questions $1.1, 1.2, \dots 1.5$ for section $1$ and similarly for sections $2$ and $3$. Suppose you pick questions $1.1, 2.1, 3.1$ when you select a problem from each section. Then, suppose that out of the remaining sections, we select $1.4, 1.5$. This option gets counted, and can be sumarized by
$$
1.1, 1.4, 1.5, 2.1, 3.1
$$
Now, suppose you pick question $1.4, 2.1, 3.1$. Then, once again, you can select any two other problems: e.g. $1.1, 1.5$. This option also gets counted. Once again, the problems that were picked are
$$
1.1, 1.4, 1.5, 2.1, 3.1.
$$